Does it make sense to define $\operatorname{Th}(V) = \lbrace \varphi \mid V \vDash \varphi \rbrace$ within $\operatorname{ZFC}$?
Does it make sense to define $\operatorname{Th}(V) = \lbrace \varphi \text{ is a formalized } \texttt{ZFC} \text{ sentence (as a set in} \operatorname{ZFC}) \mid V \vDash \varphi \rbrace$ within $\operatorname{ZFC}$ as we can define the true arithmetic $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb{N})$ within $\operatorname{ZFC}$?
Ofcourse, $V$ is not a set but a proper class in $\operatorname{ZFC}$, so the situation is slightly different between $\operatorname{Th}(V)$ and $\operatorname{Th}(\mathbb{N})$, and if the above definition is possible, that doesn't say anything about the existence
of models of $\operatorname{ZFC}$. But I think we can define $\operatorname{Th}(V)$ in the above way and it does make sense anyway.
Is it right ?
I would appreciate any help.

EDIT
Assume the formalized $\texttt{ZFC}$-language has no function symbol, no constant symbol, and only one predicate symbol as non-logical symbols and let $Var$ be the set of variables of $\texttt{ZFC}$-language within $\operatorname{ZFC}$.
So it suffices to define the truth value of every atomic formula in the form of "$x \in y$" or "$x=y$" on any variable assignment functional formula $F(x, y)$, namely
i).$\forall x\exists y  (x\in Var \to F(x, y))$
ii). $\forall x\forall y(F(x, y) \to x\in Var)$
iii).$\forall x\forall y\forall z (F(x, y) \land F(x, z) \to y=z)$
and then of every compound formula on any variable assignment functional formula $F(x, y)$ indcutively.
Here is the problem. functional formulas $F(x, y)$ are meta-concept, so they can't be quantified within $\operatorname{ZFC}$.
But $Var$ is a set, so we can prove there exists a function $f$ such that $f$ is defined on any $x\in Var$ and $f(x)=y \leftrightarrow F(x, y)$ on any $x\in Var$ within $\operatorname{ZFC}$ by the replacement axiom schema.
Thus we can define the expression $V_f \vDash \varphi$ for a formalized formula $\varphi$ on a variable assignment function $f$ inductively within $\operatorname{ZFC}$ as follows.
$V_f \vDash$ "$x\in y$" $\leftrightarrow$ $f(x)\in f(y)$
$V_f \vDash$ "$x=y$" $\leftrightarrow$ $f(x)=f(y)$
$V_f \vDash$ "$\forall x \varphi(x)$" $\leftrightarrow$ for any variable assignment function $f'$ such that for any variable $y\neq x, f'(y)=f(y)$ holds, $V_{f'} \vDash$ "$\varphi(x)$" holds.
$V_f \vDash$ "$\exists x \varphi(x)$" $\leftrightarrow$ there exists a variable assignment function $f'$ such that for any variable $y\neq x, f'(y)=f(y)$ and $V_{f'} \vDash$ "$\varphi(x)$" holds.
And for other logical connectives...
Then $V_f \vDash \varphi$ does not depend on the variable assignment function $f$ for a sentence $\varphi$, so $V \vDash \varphi$ can be defined by $V_f \vDash \varphi$ for any $f$.
This argument must be wrong. But I can't figure out what's wrong with this.

No, because there's no definition in ZFC for $V\models\dots.$ If you try to mimic the usual definition of $M\models\dots$ for sets $M$, by induction on formulas, and if you remember how definitions by induction  are formalized in ZFC, you'll find that the argument fails for $V$ because you need to quantify over proper classes. (In a theory like Morse-Kelley, which allows quantification over proper classes, the set you want can be definied.)

Also, this would contradict Tarski's undefinability theorem.

For an addendum to @AndreasBlass' comment, although Morse-Kelley set theory can define the truth predicate for first-order formulas, it cannot define the truth predicate for second-order formulas (i.e. formulas involving quantifiers over proper classes.) Also, the fact that Kelley-Morse set theory can define the (first-order) truth predicate does not contradict with Tarski's undefinability theorem as the undefinability theorem applies to the truth predicate for second-order formulas.

Thank you for the answers and expositions ! But I'm still confused... So I added my confusion about this question as EDIT. Could you point out what's wrong with that ?

@Krasiff The problem is in the definition for quantifiers. You are assuming recursively that $V_f\models \phi(x)$ has been "defined" for all variable assignments $f$. But there is a proper class of variable assignments. If you look at the details of transfinite recursion on well-founded relations, you'll see it's important that we assume that the predecessors are a set.

The answer is No as it's pointed out in the comments.
Some people were mentioning Tarski's undecidability theorem, but I couldn't understand why the usual definition of $M \vDash.....$ doesn't work for $V$, then it seems to me that Tarski's undecidability theorem not just mean there's no truth predicate but also mean the contradiction within $\operatorname{ZFC}$.
Ofcourse, that's wrong.
As Andreas Blass and spaceisdarkgreen pointed it, transfinite recursive definition (in this case, we need only recursive definition for finite ordinals because of the finiteness of the depth of formulas though) assume
the predecessors and the current value is a set on each step of recursion and then so every value at every ordinal for the result class function, or $G$ for which $F(\alpha) = G(F\upharpoonright \alpha)$ would take a proper class as its argument and quantify over them, so it does not make sense.
If we want to try to apply recursion to the definition of $C \vDash.....$ for a proper class $C$, the recursion still works for formulas not containing the quantifiers in each of a variable assignment function $f$ separately but uniformly, however, for formulas containing the quantifiers, the definition needs all of those of predecessors for variable assignments, then it become a proper class so we can't apply recursion in such a way.
Though my misunderstanding is in the very basic level and I should have realized it by myself, I have finally understood it thanks to the kind comments.
I'm sorry for bothering you all.
Thank you all for your help!

Tarski's theorem is a more fundamental obstruction, since it shows that it is outright impossible for a (first-order) satisfaction predicate for $V$ to exist, not just that the naive way to define it fails. It is possible in some cases to have a satisfaction predicate for a proper class (e.g. if large cardinals exist, there is a satisfaction predicate for $L$), but not in general and never for $V.$
